# private-bower : git cache?

Tags: git, caching, bower

I have a private bower installation using https://github.com/Hacklone/private-bower.

It's working great without any cache, but I would like to cache the public Git repos. I used the following configuration:

```
 "repositoryCache": {
    "cachePrivate": false,
    "git": {
        "enabled": false,
        "cacheDirectory": "./gitRepoCache",
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 6789,
        "publicAccessURL" : null,
        "refreshTimeout": 10
    }
}
```

I do see the public git projects inside the ./gitRepoCache folder, but when installing my bower projects, bower tries to

```
 resolve git://localhost:6790/qunit#~1.16.0
```

I can see why it is doing that based on our configuration, but I have absolutely no idea on what I should do so that I have an url "gitaccessible" pointing to the folder ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that private-bower is launching its own git-daemon, so the only thing that missed is the publicAccessURL property, which is returned when bower install is run. Setting publicAccessURL to the machine's IP running private-bower made the trick.

Comment: Can `publicAccessURL` be localhost?

Comment: Public access is the url returned by private-bower, indicating where to get the project. If it is localhost, then only a client on the same machine as private-bower will be able to checkout the bower component.
If you wish to have different developers from diferent computers accessing the repo, you need to set in the publicAccessURL a value which can be accessed from the developer's computers.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. I am trying to test run private-bower so I'm running this on local windows os, could this be a problem? Because I can't see anything on `https://localhost:6789` which is a default git-deamon url

Comment: Ok, had other problems in git config.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue and I think it is worth to recommend the docker  of `private-bower`, https://github.com/tandrup/docker-private-bower

On my own I have just used the config file, changing the parameters to match my IP address and path.

```
...
"git": {
   "enabled": true,
   "cacheDirectory": "/data/gitRepoCache",
   "host": "0.0.0.0",
   "port": 6789,
   "publicAccessURL" : "<address>:6789",
   "refreshTimeout": 10
},
...
```

Setting my project `.bowerrc` file:

```
{"registry": "http://<address>:5678"}
```

This config is sufficient. Though when calling `bower install` on my machine, **all the libraries were still downloaded from the repos.**

To fix it, you have to call

```
bower cache clean
```

And install the dependencies again. Then, they will be cached on your server too.